# Jenkins master can't connect to Subversion, but slave can

Tags: jenkins, svn, master-slave, svnkit

I am using Subversion plugin in Jenkins. My master machine (Windows) is unable to connect to SVN server (using Apache Subversion v1.7) via svn+ssh throwing exception

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building on master in workspace c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\w4ManagerWorkspace
Updating svn+ssh://10.74.1.41/data/subversion/svn/tools/testComplete/trunk/W4Manager at revision '2022-12-01T10:31:08.582 +0100' --quiet
Using sole credentials arpc_ta/****** in realm ‘svn+ssh://10.74.1.41’
ERROR: Failed to update svn+ssh://10.74.1.41/data/subversion/svn/tools/testComplete/trunk/W4Manager
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E210002: There was a problem while connecting to 10.74.1.41:22
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNSSHConnector.open(SVNSSHConnector.java:145)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNConnection.open(SVNConnection.java:79)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.openConnection(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1282)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.testConnection(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.getRepositoryUUID(SVNRepository.java:268)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.createRepository(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:103)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepository(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:211)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.updateInternal(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:210)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.update(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:115)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgUpdate.run(SvnNgUpdate.java:40)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgUpdate.run(SvnNgUpdate.java:18)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1239)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:311)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:291)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:387)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:159)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1064)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1040)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1013)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1172)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1155)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:960)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:883)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1213)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:637)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:509)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1888)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:431)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to 10.74.1.41:22
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:781)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.ssh.SshHost.openConnection(SshHost.java:225)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.ssh.SshHost.openSession(SshHost.java:153)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.ssh.SshSessionPool.openSession(SshSessionPool.java:85)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNSSHConnector.open(SVNSSHConnector.java:122)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: **Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.**
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.getOrWaitForConnectionInfo(KexManager.java:95)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.getConnectionInfo(TransportManager.java:237)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:732)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: **Fatal error during MAC startup!**
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.finishKex(KexManager.java:298)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.handleMessage(KexManager.java:571)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:790)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:502)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ERROR: Subversion update failed
java.io.IOException: Fatal error during MAC startup!
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.finishKex(KexManager.java:298)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.handleMessage(KexManager.java:571)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:790)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:502)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.getOrWaitForConnectionInfo(KexManager.java:95)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.getConnectionInfo(TransportManager.java:237)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:732)
Caused: java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to 10.74.1.41:22
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:781)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.ssh.SshHost.openConnection(SshHost.java:225)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.ssh.SshHost.openSession(SshHost.java:153)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.ssh.SshSessionPool.openSession(SshSessionPool.java:85)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNSSHConnector.open(SVNSSHConnector.java:122)
Caused: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E210002: There was a problem while connecting to 10.74.1.41:22
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNSSHConnector.open(SVNSSHConnector.java:145)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNConnection.open(SVNConnection.java:79)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.openConnection(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1282)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.testConnection(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.getRepositoryUUID(SVNRepository.java:268)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.createRepository(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:103)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepository(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:211)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.updateInternal(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:210)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.update(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:115)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgUpdate.run(SvnNgUpdate.java:40)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgUpdate.run(SvnNgUpdate.java:18)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1239)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:311)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:291)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:387)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:159)
Caused: hudson.scm.subversion.UpdaterException: failed to perform svn update
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:214)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1064)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1040)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1013)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1172)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1155)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:960)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:883)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1213)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:637)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:509)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1888)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:431)
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
Finished: FAILURE
```

The same Jenkins project run from slave machine is successful. On my slave machine Jenkins is running as windows service.

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building remotely on slaveMachine (slave_1) in workspace c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\w4ManagerWorkspace
Updating svn+ssh://10.74.1.41/data/subversion/svn/tools/testComplete/trunk/W4Manager at revision '2022-12-01T12:30:51.663 +0100' --quiet
Using sole credentials arpc_ta/****** in realm ‘svn+ssh://10.74.1.41’
Using sole credentials arpc_ta/****** in realm ‘svn+ssh://10.74.1.41’
At revision 7401
```

In projects configuration in Jenkins is shown, that something is not in order with message "Unable to access the repository"

[image]

However, when I run the same project on my slave machine, the connection is successful, and Jenkins does not show in console any error. svn update command finishes successfully. Both my master and slave machines are Windows server VMs with. Connection from master to SVN from TortoiseSVN is successful, and I am able to checkout the repository. I used SVN few years without problems, Subversion plugin was just installed to Jenkins.

Found similar issues e.g. [Jenkins Master-Slave: Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50136080/jenkins-master-slave-key-exchange-was-not-finished-connection-is-closed/52144654#52144654) or https://support.tmatesoft.com/t/svn-e210002-svnkit-doesnt-connect-to-remote-repository/2480/13, with solution to edit config file /etc/ssh/sshd_config on svn server, but I don't think that can be the issue, since from slave machine the connection is successful. I checked also Java version, they are the same on both windows servers.

Tried also different credential types, public key authentication and user/pw from scm console of Jenkins [jenkinsUrl]/scm/SubversionSCM/enterCredential but it throws the same error, just from the line **Fatal error during MAC startup!**

edit: On SVN server in /var/log/secure there is Connection closed message from my master machine (10.74.37.1), no other error or details. From slave machine (10.74.37.28) the connection is accepted

```
Dec  5 14:47:11 xlcppt28 sshd[24808]: Connection closed by 10.74.37.1 port 57664 [preauth]
Dec  5 14:47:13 xlcppt28 sshd[24811]: Accepted password for arpc_ta from 10.74.37.28 port 57941 ssh2
Dec  5 14:47:13 xlcppt28 sshd[24811]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user arpc_ta by (uid=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was resolved with updating Jenkins and then every plugin in Jenkins (as my Jenkins server is offline, that wasn't 2 clicks..) I also updated Java.